# Hibernate Relationships (One to Many, Many to Many, One to One)

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project and wish to implement Hibernate in it.  I have viewed many videos discussing relationships giving examples such as Customer-Order where a Customer can have many orders but Orders refer to only one customer.  Or, Students-Courses where students can have many courses and vice versa.  In my particular situation I have a Customer table and a Salutation table where I want to make sure a standard set of salutations are used so I have the following:

[image]

I am not sure how to set this type of relationship up.  In all of the examples I have seen, you would place a reference to a Salutation Object in the Customer table but that does not seem to make sense.  The Salutation field in my Customers table below is of type int.  So how do you form a relationship for instances such as this?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you are learning and hasn't tagged any other tag other than `hibernate` like `spring` or `spring-boot`, let me go in details for you to get your job done.

Lets take example of `Cart and Items` table. . . . . We use the foreign key constraint for one-to-many mapping:

```
CREATE TABLE `Cart` (
  `cart_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 
CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cart_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cart_id` (`cart_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `Cart` (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If you are using springboot then you can skip configuration step as it is pre configured with just one dependency.

**Maven Dependencies**

We will then add the Hibernate and H2 driver dependencies to our pom.xml file. The Hibernate dependency uses JBoss logging and it automatically gets added as transitive dependencies:

- Hibernate version 5.2.7.Final
- H2 driver version 1.4.197

Please visit the Maven central repository for the latest versions of Hibernate and the H2 dependencies.

**Hibernate Configuration**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:h2:mem:spring_hibernate_one_to_many</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateAnnotationUtil Class**

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 
private SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
      
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
      configure("hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml").build();
    Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
             
    return sessionFactory;
}   
 
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if(sessionFactory == null) sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

**The Models**

The mapping related configurations will be done using JPA annotations in the model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART")
public class Cart {
 
    //...
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
    private Set<Items> items;
     
    // getters and setters
}
```

Please note that the @OneToMany annotation is used to define the property in Items class that will be used to map the mappedBy variable. That's why we have a property named “cart” in the Items class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Items {
     
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
    private Cart cart;
 
    public Items() {}
     
    // getters and setters
}
```

**In Action**

In the test program, we are creating a class with a main() method for getting the Hibernate Session and saving the model objects into the database implementing the one-to-many association:

```
sessionFactory = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
System.out.println("Session created");
         
tx = session.beginTransaction();
 
session.save(cart);
session.save(item1);
session.save(item2);
         
tx.commit();
System.out.println("Cart ID=" + cart.getId());
System.out.println("item1 ID=" + item1.getId()
  + ", Foreign Key Cart ID=" + item.getCart().getId());
System.out.println("item2 ID=" + item2.getId()
+ ", Foreign Key Cart ID=" + item.getCart().getId());
```

This is the output of our test program:

```
 Session created    

Hibernate: insert into CART values ()    

Hibernate: insert into ITEMS (cart_id)

  values (?)    

Hibernate: insert into ITEMS (cart_id)    

  values (?)

Cart ID=7


item1 ID=11, Foreign Key Cart ID=7


item2 ID=12, Foreign Key Cart ID=7


Closing SessionFactory
```

**The `@ManyToOne` Annotation**

As we've seen above, we can specify a `many-to-one` relationship by using the `@ManyToOne` annotation. A `many-to-one` mapping means that many instances of this entity are mapped to one instance of another entity – many items in one cart.

The **@ManyToOne** annotation lets us create bidirectional relationships, too. I'll cover this in detail further.

**Inconsistencies and Ownership**

Now, if Cart referenced Items, but Items didn't, in turn, reference Cart, our relationship would be unidirectional. The objects would also have a natural consistency.

In our case, though, the relationship is bidirectional, bringing in the possibility of inconsistency.

Let's imagine a situation where a developer wants to add item1 to cart and item2 to cart2, but makes a mistake so that the references between cart2 and item2 become inconsistent:

```
Cart cart1 = new Cart();
Cart cart2 = new Cart();
 
Items item1 = new Items(cart1);
Items item2 = new Items(cart2); 
Set<Items> itemsSet = new HashSet<Items>();
itemsSet.add(item1);
itemsSet.add(item2); 
cart1.setItems(itemsSet); // wrong!
```

As shown above, item2 references cart2 whereas cart2 doesn't reference item2 — and that's bad.

How should Hibernate save item2 to the database? Will item2 `foreign key` reference cart1 or cart2?

We resolve this ambiguity using the idea of an owning side of the relationship — references belonging to the owning side take precedence and are saved to the database.

**items as the Owning Side**
it's a good practice to mark many-to-one side as the owning side.

In other words, Items would be the owning side and Cart the inverse side, which is exactly what we did earlier.

So, how did we achieve this?

By including the mappedBy attribute in the Cart class, we mark it as the inverse side.

At the same time, we also annotate the Items.cart field with @ManyToOne, making Items the owning side.

Going back to our “inconsistency” example, now Hibernate knows that the item2‘s reference is more important and will save item2‘s reference to the database.

Let's check the result:

```
item1 ID=1, Foreign Key Cart ID=1

item2 ID=2, Foreign Key Cart ID=2
```

**Cart as the Owning Side**

It's also possible to mark the one-to-many side as the owning side, and many-to-one side as the inverse side.

Although this is not a recommended practice, let's go ahead and give it a try.

The code snippet below shows the implementation of one-to-many side as the owning side:

```
public class ItemsOIO {
     
    //  ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private CartOIO cart;
    //..
}
 
public class CartOIO {
     
    //..  
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id") // we need to duplicate the physical information
    private Set<ItemsOIO> items;
    //..
}
```

Notice how we removed the mappedBy element and set the many-to-one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false.

If we run the same code, the result will be the opposite:

```
item1 ID=1, Foreign Key Cart ID=1

item2 ID=2, Foreign Key Cart ID=1
```

As shown above, now item2 belongs to cart.

Hope that was enough from learning prespective.

Comment: Please assign bounty sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must learn about various kind of relationships.

The diagram you use display a [one-to-one relationship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDnL1gwCE0o) externalized inside another entity. You can do it but nothing forces you to do so. Most of the time it goes well. Freedom.

> In my particular situation I have a Customer table and a Salutation table where I want to make sure a standard set of salutations

That text you have wrotten is telling me that you have 1 Customer and many possible Salutations. If the webuser will be able to choose only one of them, then your diagram is good.

Otherwise if the webuser can choose many of them, then you must look at a [one-to-many relationship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ghacRLkj1w).

[Many-to-many relationships](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-o0d_e9mW8) are existing too but you are not in that use case.

You can learn from the official documentation of your preferred relational database. But the basics to understand are in SQL tutorials. I love these [one](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) or the [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html) one's.

Comment: So, I apologize, my table should have been more clear.  In the customer table that should be salutation_id.  So it is a foreign key in the Customer table referencing the primary key in the Salutation table.  And in the Salutation table that should salutation_id instead of just salutation. The goal is to ensure that there are a set of standard salutations the customer can use.  The customer can only select one salutation (Mr., Mrs. Ms., etc..)  I would then do a join to pull the salutation_description.  Hope that clears things up.